# expand java 2d array at left and right

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2D java array, for example:

```
int[]][]arr = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}
```

I want to copy several left and right columns of this to right and left sides of my array. This my target:

```
int[][] arr = {{5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2}, {11, 12, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 7, 8}}
```

In real life my array is very large (1500x600) and I need a fast solution.
I know about `System.arraycopy` but can not figure out how to use it here.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? You are trying to copy values in your first array into another array?

Comment: *"but can not figure out how to use it here."*  Give it your best attempt.  If it fails, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: leigero, Yes I need to create another array.

Comment: I guess you want to use a window of a certain size (5 in your example) in a circular array. Is that correct? Or do you have an other reason to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the arrays you posted as example:

```
int[][] arr1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}}
int[][] arr2 = new int[2][10];

// ...

for(int n = 0; n < arr1.length; n++) {
    System.arrayCopy(arr1[n], 0, arr2[n], 0, 2);
    System.arrayCopy(arr1[n], 0, arr2[n], 2, 6);
    System.arrayCopy(arr1[n], 4, arr2[n], 6, 2);
}

// here arr2 will have what you want
```

Comment: I think, in for loop it must be `n++`. Also why three `arrayCopy`statements?

Comment: I think you mixed the indices. This results in `{1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6}`.

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli sorry, in Australia is time to go to bed and half my brain is already asleep, fixed the <code>n++</code> part. You need three arrayCopy because you are doing three different "copies": the left part, the "right" one and the original content in the middle.